# Из php не видит функцию javascript - как исправить?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть магазин на `wordpress+woocommerce`. 
Для того, чтобы для потенциального покупателя сделать некоторые удобные вещи во время покупки, я запоминаю его куку. 
Функции прописываю в файле **custom.js**, который подключен через **functions.php**

```
function getCookie() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var cookie = cookies.filter(function(str) {
        str = str.trim();
        return str == 'user=fooboo';
    });
    return cookie;
}

function setCookie(name, value, options) {
    options = options || {};

    var expires = options.expires;

    if (typeof expires == "number" && expires) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + expires * 1000);
        expires = options.expires = d;
    }
    if (expires && expires.toUTCString) {
        options.expires = expires.toUTCString();
    }

    value = encodeURIComponent(value);

    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value;

    for (var propName in options) {
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName;
        var propValue = options[propName];
        if (propValue !== true) {
            updatedCookie += "=" + propValue;
        }
    }

    document.cookie = updatedCookie;
}

function deleteCookie(user) {
  setCookie(user, "", {
    expires: -1
  })
}
```

Когда покупатель уже заказал товар, мне нужно его куку удалить. 
Для чего я подключаюсь к хуку в  **functions.php**

```
function delete_сookie($order_id, $old_status, $new_status) { 
    if( ($new_status == "completed") || ($new_status == "processing") ) { 
?>
  <script>
    deleteCookie('fooboo');
    console.log("expire");
  </script>
<?php }
}
```

Но, получаю ошибку:

> ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined

Как это исправить и сделать возможность подключения к функции удаления?

Comment: Так у вас код `deleteCookie('fooboo');` исполняется перед тем как подгрузится файл `custom.js` с этой функцией. Поэтому и `ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined`

Comment: @Dantessss функции `deleteCookie` и `setCookie` объявлены в одном и том же файле.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не запущен файл jquery.cookie. Без него использованные вами функции не определены.

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду, как это не определены, когда сама кука записывается, что видно в консоли? с удалением возникают проблемы